# Flyway java version 11.0.2 upgrade

Tags: flyway

I am trying to update the the java version packaged in flyway and is currently showing the following. how do i upgrade to latest?

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to upgrade the JRE shipped with the command line bundle of Flyway.

In this case, if you remove JRE folder from the install directory it will attempt to use the version of the JRE which is installed on your system.

Unfortunately, there is no upgrade path for this folder but you could replace the content of it with the install folder of a newer JRE if you wish to keep it local.